# Java Eclipse folder with git

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I've been working on a Java package using eclipse and have been using git for version control. I accidentally `git rm'd` a file, committed and pushed it.

In order to revert the effects, I did a checkout of the deleted files from a previous commit, did another commit and pushed it back. Now I have my files back.

However, those files do not show up in the package in Eclipse -- what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sometimes get inconsistencies between Eclipse and Git, to solve this I usually just refresh the Eclipse project. I could be more complex than this, but eliminate the simplest solution first.